# BeautifulSoup - multiple cards with multiple nested values

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read all "card" in the California State Lotto page:

There are X drawings and each drawing is represented with a 'Card':

**Example Card**

```
<div class="card"><div class="card-header" id="heading-1"><button class="accordion--toggle w-100 collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1"><div class="row align-items-center no-gutters"><div class="col-10 offset-0 offset-md-1"><div class="row no-gutters"><div class="col-6 col-md-3"><p aria-hidden="true">NOV 26, 2019</p><div class="sr-only">Draw Date, NOV 26, 2019</div></div><div class="col-6 col-md-3 text-center text-md-left"><p aria-hidden="true">#1506</p><div class="sr-only">Draw Number,
#1506</div></div><div class="col-12 col-md-4"><p class="d-block d-md-none mt-2" aria-hidden="true">Winning Numbers</p><ul class="list-inline winning-numbers" aria-hidden="true"> <li class="list-inline-item">8</li><li class="list-inline-item">27</li><li class="list-inline-item">29</li><li class="list-inline-item">38</li><li class="list-inline-item">43</li><li class="list-inline-item gameball">13<span class="sr-only">Superball</span></li></ul><div class="sr-only">Winning Numbers,  8 27 29 38 43 Mega,
#13</div></div><div class="col-0 col-md-2 d-none d-md-block"><p aria-hidden="true">13</p></div></div></div><div class="col-2 col-md-1 text-right align-self-start"><span class="fa-stack fa-2x"><i class="fal fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fas fa-stack-1x fa-plus"></i></span></div></div></button></div><div id="collapse-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-1" style=""><div class="card-body"><div class="row no-gutters"><div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2"><p class="accordion--content-heading">Detailed Draw Results for California</p><div class="last-draw-details"><div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-striped"><thead class="table-head"><tr><th class="table-head-in-accordion" scope="col">Matching Numbers</th><th class="table-head-in-accordion" scope="col">Winning Tickets</th><th class="table-head-in-accordion" scope="col">Prize Amounts</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>5 + Mega</td><td>0</td> <td>$226,000,000</td></tr> <tr><td>5</td><td>0</td> <td>$607,765</td></tr> <tr><td>4 + Mega</td><td>2</td> <td>$14,957</td></tr> <tr><td>4</td><td>77</td> <td>$437</td></tr> <tr><td>3 + Mega</td><td>195</td> <td>$196</td></tr> <tr><td>3</td><td>4,902</td> <td>$9</td></tr> <tr><td>2 + Mega</td><td>4,263</td> <td>$9</td></tr> <tr><td>1 + Mega</td><td>33,267</td> <td>$3</td></tr> <tr><td>Mega</td><td>77,134</td> <td>$2</td></tr> <tr class="total"><td>Total Winning Tickets</td><td>119,840</td><td></td></tr> </tbody>  </table>  </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>
```

I am able to extract the first card with the following code:

```
for p in soup.find('p', {'class': 'draw-cards--draw-number'}).parent.find_all('p'):
draw_info.append(p.text)


for li in soup.find('li', {'class':'list-inline-item'}).parent.find_all('li'):
winning_num5_5.append(int(li.text.strip()[0:2]))

draw_num = int(draw_info[2][6:])
draw_date = draw_info[1][4:]
draw_info[0] = winning_num5_5
draw_mega = winning_num5_5[5]
draw_five = winning_num5_5[0:5]

#print(draw_info)
print(f'draw date is {draw_date} and draw number is {draw_num} winning numbers are {draw_five} and mega is {draw_mega}')
```

**Output is:**

> draw date is NOV 26, 2019 and draw number is 1506 winning numbers are
>   [8, 27, 29, 38, 43] and mega is 13

**Question:**
How do I read ALL cards on the site (note:  there are 1506 drawings thus there should be 1506 cards representing all past drawings)

**URL for all Mega Test Results**

https://www.calottery.com/draw-games/mega-millions#section-content-2-3

Comment: and if just make requests to https://www.calottery.com/api/DrawGameApi/DrawGamePastDrawResults/15/6/20 ??

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar you are faster than me :D

Comment: here some requests https://pasteboard.co/IIPpGhj.jpg

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar yea i captured the `XHR`, he will need to load `json` and go on.

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar I still don't see how I access the cards.  Thanks

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I still don't see how I can access the cards, Thanks

Comment: I have an solution just using requests and Pandas...but I don't know if you want this way

Comment: @yopines check my answer below

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη thats beautiful code and the effort is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @yopines you welcome ;) glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tracked the website to see from where the `JavaScript` is rendered, I've been able to fetch the `url` from where the `XHR` done which is [*Click Here*](https://www.calottery.com/api/DrawGameApi/DrawGamePastDrawResults/15/1/20).

Therefore, I catches the `start page` and `end page` which is `/15/1/20` to `/15/18/20`.

I've looped over the pages and accessed the `dictionary` of the data and sorted it for you.

```
import requests

for page in range(1, 19):
    try:
        r = requests.get(
            f"https://www.calottery.com/api/DrawGameApi/DrawGamePastDrawResults/15/{page}/20").json()
        print(f"{'*' * 20}Extracting Page# {page}{'*' * 21}")
        for item in r['PreviousDraws']:
            winning_numbers = item['WinningNumbers']
            print("Date: {} Draw#: {} Win#: {:>2} {:>2} {:>2} {:>2} {:>2} Mega# {}".format(
                item['DrawDate'][0:10], item['DrawNumber'], * [winning_numbers[num]['Number'] for num in '01234'], winning_numbers['5']['Number']))
        print('*' * 60)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Good Bye!")
        break
```

> the code is simple but the efforts taken to make it easy is much :D

Simple of the Output:

```
********************Extracting Page# 1*********************
Date: 2019-11-26 Draw#: 1506 Win#:  8 27 29 38 43 Mega# 13
Date: 2019-11-22 Draw#: 1505 Win#:  7 12 17 49 53 Mega# 24
Date: 2019-11-19 Draw#: 1504 Win#: 22 43 44 47 66 Mega# 22
Date: 2019-11-15 Draw#: 1503 Win#: 12 19 34 35 68 Mega# 20
Date: 2019-11-12 Draw#: 1502 Win#: 19 30 44 56 65 Mega# 24
Date: 2019-11-08 Draw#: 1501 Win#:  3  4 10 39 58 Mega# 14
Date: 2019-11-05 Draw#: 1500 Win#:  2  9 24 49 54 Mega# 19
Date: 2019-11-05 Draw#: 1500 Win#:  2  9 24 49 54 Mega# 19
Date: 2019-11-01 Draw#: 1499 Win#:  9 20 36 41 54 Mega# 22
Date: 2019-10-29 Draw#: 1498 Win#:  4  9 17 27 39 Mega# 22
Date: 2019-10-25 Draw#: 1497 Win#: 16 24 25 52 60 Mega# 6
Date: 2019-10-22 Draw#: 1496 Win#:  5 11 14 23 25 Mega# 10
Date: 2019-10-18 Draw#: 1495 Win#: 18 58 60 65 67 Mega# 20
Date: 2019-10-15 Draw#: 1494 Win#:  4 12 14 35 70 Mega# 2
Date: 2019-10-11 Draw#: 1493 Win#: 14 22 30 37 60 Mega# 8
Date: 2019-10-08 Draw#: 1492 Win#:  5  8 10 17 48 Mega# 23
Date: 2019-10-04 Draw#: 1491 Win#: 11 38 44 48 70 Mega# 17
Date: 2019-10-01 Draw#: 1490 Win#: 10 17 39 42 59 Mega# 3
Date: 2019-09-27 Draw#: 1489 Win#: 12 20 31 43 45 Mega# 20
Date: 2019-09-24 Draw#: 1488 Win#:  6 14 24 42 46 Mega# 9
************************************************************
```

Run Code Online: [Click Here](https://repl.it/@AmericanY/Draw)